# Finding a square integrable dominating function for function class

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, integration, asymptotics, taylor-series

***problem statement***

For any $x \in R^d$, consider the function $$\phi(x,a) = \min_{1\leq j \leq k} \|x-a_j\|^2,$$
where $a = (a_1, \dots, a_k) \in R^{kd}$ and $\| \cdot \|$ is the $L_p$ norm for any $p \geq 1$.
Let $X$ be a continuous random vector in $R^d$ with distribution $P$ such that $\int \|x\|^2 dP(x) < \infty$ and assume measurability is taken care of for all functions.

Consider for some fixed $b$ and for some $R>0$, the class of functions: 
$$ G_R := \{ g(x) = \phi(x,a) - \phi(x,b) : \| a - b\| \leq R \} $$

I'd like to find a  function $F(x)$ and constant $R>0$ such that:

1) $F(x) \geq |g(x)|, \forall g(x) \in G_R$.

2) $\int {F(x)}^2 dP(x) = O(R^2),$ and $\forall \epsilon >0, \int {F(x)}^2 1\{F(x) > \epsilon\} dP(x) = o(R^2)$ as $R \rightarrow 0$.

***my attempt***

I have a solution for the case of $p=2$ (Euclidean norm) which I have trouble generalizing for other $L_p$ norms.

For $a = (a_1, \dots, a_k)$, let $A_j$ denote the set of points in $R^d$ that are closest to $a_j$ among $\{a_1, \dots, a_k \}$ according to $\| \cdot \|$).

Notice that if $x \in interior({A_j})$ and $h$ sufficiently small,
\begin{equation}
\label{jlinearexpansioneqn}
 \phi(x;{a+h}) = \|x-a_j-h_j\|^2 = \|x-a_j\|^2 - 2h_j'(x-a_j) + \|h_j\|^2.
 \end{equation}
Hence, since we restrict analysis to continuous densities, boundaries between $A_j$ and $A_i$ have zero measure.  So we have the following taylor expansion:
\begin{equation}
\label{linearexpansioneqn}
 \phi(x;{a+h}) =  \phi(x;{a}) + {h}'\delta(x,{a}) + \|{{h}}\|r(x,{a},{h}), 
 \end{equation}
where $\delta(x,{a})$ is the gradient of $\phi(x;{a})$, the $k$ vector of $L^2(P)$ functions with element $j$ equal to $-2(x-a_j) 1\{x\in A_j\}$.

Furthermore,

$$ r(x,{a},{h}) = \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{\|{h_j}\|^2 1\{ x \in A_j\} } {{\|{h}\|}} \rightarrow 0 \text{ as } {h} \rightarrow 0 \quad \text{ a.s. in }  x .$$

In addition, 
\begin{align}
\label{remainderdominationeqn}
\begin{split}
    |r(x,{a},{h})| &\leq {\|{h}\|}^{-1} ( |{h}'\delta(x,{a})| + \max_j | \|{x-a_j-h_j}\|^2 - \|{x-a_j}\|^2   | ) \\
&\leq  \|{\delta(x,{a})}\|  +{\|{h}\|}^{-1}  \sum_j | \|{x-a_j-h_j}\|^2 - \|{x-a_j}\|^2   | ) \\
&\leq C(1+\|{x}\|)
\end{split}
\end{align}
for some $C>0$ and ${h}$ sufficiently small.

Let $R>0$ be small enough such that the above domination is true for $a=b,h=a-b$. Then by the expansion above and Cauchy-Schwarz:
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
    |g(x) | & =  \left| \phi(x;{a}) -  \phi(x;b)  \right| \\
    &= \left| ({a} - b)'\delta(x,b)  + { \|{a} - b}\| r(x,b,{a} - b) \right|  \\
    &\leq {\|{a} - b}\| \|{ \delta(x,b)}\|  + C { \|{a} - b}\|(1+\|{x}\|) \\
    &= B(x) \|{{a} - b}\|,
\end{split}
\end{align}
where $B(x) =  \|{ \delta(x,b)}\|  + C(1+\|{x}\|) \in L^2 (P)$.
The dominating function $F(x) = RB(x)$ satisfies 1) and 2).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The introduction of the $p$-norm looks a little bit strange for me, since the rest seems to be for the $2$-norm case. Can you explain where this type of "generalization" comes from? What is the context?

Comment: My attempt is for the p=2 case because the gradient and the hessian of $\phi(x, a)$ is simpler. The gradient when $p \neq 2$ is already pretty ugly.  As for the hessian, it is the identity matrix for $p=2$ but it changes along the boundary for $p \neq 2$ so it does not seem like the method of taylor expansion would help in $p \neq 2$ cases. I'm interested in this problem because in statistics, we check that a criterion function (in this case $\phi$) satisfies certain properties to derive asymptotic behavior for the minimizer/maximizer of $P\phi(\cdot,a)$.